# writting xml file & storing on local disk

Tags: javascript, xmlwriter

I was following on the above mentioned topic since long & finally got to see this link " http://flesler.blogspot.in/2008/03/xmlwriter-for-javascript.html ". But, unfortunately, following this method on chrome i got the error saying : " Uncaught ReferenceError: XMLWriter is not defined"
I tried to reply on that blog itself but i think it is no longer available & hence i choose to write here.

can anyone hekp me out with this please.

Comment: ActiveX is basically dead technology. You can write XML with javascript using the DOM or string concatenation though...

Comment: @Evert — That misses out the "storing on local disk" part

Comment: The link OP posted does not store anything on a local disk either.

Comment: @Quentin  @ Evert - I searched on this topic already & got to follow blobs to store file locally , now I'm writting to this file with the article mentioned under the link http://flesler.blogspot.in/2008/03/xmlwriter-for-javascript.html but I'm getting the errors as said in the question. Do you have any idea that can help me please ?